# DropDownListFor does not sleet the intended item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, selectedvalue, dropdownlistfor

combo loads ok, but item "3" does not get selected.
How can I select this item?

Here's the code I'm using for the list and selection.

```
@Code

    Dim Items As New Collections.Generic.List(Of SelectListItem)
    Items.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Value = "1", .Text = "Usuario registrado"})
    Items.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Value = "2", .Text = "Administrador"})
    Items.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Value = "3", .Text = "Supervisor"})
    Items.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Value = "4", .Text = "Usuario de pulmón"})
    Items.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Value = "5", .Text = "Usuario de picking"})

End Code


@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Profile)
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Profile, New SelectList(Items, "Value", "Text", "3"))
```

Controller. In this section I initialize the profile property.

```
    Public Function Edit() As ActionResult
    Dim Model As New EditModel

    Dim User = Membership.FindUsersByName(Request("UserName"))(Request("UserName"))
    Model.UserName = User.UserName

    If Roles.IsUserInRole(User.UserName, Models.AppRoles.Administrador.ToString) Then
        Model.Profile = Models.AppRoles.Administrador

    ElseIf Roles.IsUserInRole(User.UserName, Models.AppRoles.Supervisor.ToString) Then
        Model.Profile = Models.AppRoles.Supervisor

    ElseIf Roles.IsUserInRole(User.UserName, Models.AppRoles.UsuarioPulmon.ToString) Then
        Model.Profile = Models.AppRoles.UsuarioPulmon

    ElseIf Roles.IsUserInRole(User.UserName, Models.AppRoles.UsuarioPicking.ToString) Then
        Model.Profile = Models.AppRoles.UsuarioPicking

    ElseIf Roles.IsUserInRole(User.UserName, Models.AppRoles.UsuarioRegistrado.ToString) Then
        Model.Profile = Models.AppRoles.UsuarioRegistrado

    End If

    Model.Email = User.Email

    Return View(Model)
End Function



Public Class EditModel

<Required()>
<Display(Name:="Perfil")>
Public Property Profile() As Models.AppRoles

<Required()> _
<Display(Name:="Nombre de usuario")> _
Public Property UserName() As String

<Required()> _
<DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)> _
<Display(Name:="E-mail")> _
Public Property Email() As String
```

End Class

```
Namespace Models
Public Enum AppRoles
    UsuarioRegistrado = 1
    Administrador = 2
    Supervisor = 3
    UsuarioPulmon = 4
    UsuarioPicking = 5
End Enum
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `Profile` property with the value you want to be selected in the list. If `Profile` is not an `int`, create a property `SelectedProfileId` and use this property

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.SelectedProfileId, New SelectList(Items, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: The problem is that Profile property is an ENUM. I use a your "SelectedProfile" property as Integer and work fine. (I extended mi code sample) THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I bind it to Model's property, and it works.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Profile, New SelectList(Items, "Value", "Text", Model.Profile))
```